# Can I get a UK visitor visa before my US I797A is stamped?

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I am currently in US on H1B visa. I have an I797A approved, but do not have the visa stamped yet. I plan to go my home country, and get the US visa stamped before traveling to the UK.

The UK visitor visa asks for evidence which shows that I have permission to enter the country where I am applying from. I will get my US visa stamped and return to the US about 3 weeks before my intended UK travel. Will the UK consulate accept the I797A as evidence for now, or should I wait until I get the US visa stamped to apply?